# JGraphT: How can I get minimum edge count between to vertex?

Tags: graph, jgrapht

I want to get minimum edge count between to vertex with jgrapht, Not shortest path.But I still have no idea after tried many times;

Comment: What's wrong with a basic breadth first search?

Comment: Got it! Thank you!